# Stripe Connect - Showing Connected Account Name on Receipts

Tags: stripe-payments

Our Stripe Account 'New Startup ABC' is using Stripe Connect to make charges on behalf of vendors on our platform.

Our problem is that all receipts are showing 'New Startup ABC' as the business to which the payment was made, rather than 'Vendor 123'

Here's how we're creating the charge, and getting the resulting receipt url to send via SMS to customers.

```
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
      'amount' => $chargingTodayStripe,
      'currency' => 'cad',
      'customer' => $customerStripeID,
      'description' => 'O-'.$orderID,
      'destination' => $locationConnectID
 ]);

 $receiptURL = $charge->receipt_url;
```

I spoke with a Stripe agent, but they weren't even aware of the receipt_url parameter, so I was hoping I'd have better luck here.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your use of [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges), and you should review the importance of the [various charge flows](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#choosing-approach). You can use the [updated `transfer_data` parameters](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#differences) to control the `destination` account and use the [optional `on_behalf_of` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-on_behalf_of) to control the merchant of record.